# Binary Tree being filled with zeros

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am writing a binary tree (for only numbers zero or larger) in C++ and for some reason all the values but the head seem to be zero (when I add an element) and I am not sure why that is happening. This seems like it would be rather obvious but I've been staring at this for 2 hours and can't seem to figure out what is happening.

Here is my BinaryTree.cpp:

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"

BinaryTree::Node::Node(){
    lChild = NULL;
    rChild = NULL;
    data = -1;
}

BinaryTree::Node::Node(int data){
    lChild = NULL;
    rChild = NULL;
    data = data;
}

BinaryTree::BinaryTree(){
    head = new Node();
}

BinaryTree::BinaryTree(int num){
    head = new Node(num);
}

void BinaryTree::addElement(int data){
    addElement(data, head);
}

void BinaryTree::addElement(int data, Node * node){

    if( node -> data != -1){
        if(node -> data > data){
            if(node -> lChild){
                addElement(data, node -> lChild);
            }
            else{
                node ->lChild = new Node(data);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(node -> rChild){
                addElement(data, node -> rChild);
            }
            else{
                node -> rChild = new Node(data);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        node -> data = data;
    }
}
```

Here is my BinaryTree.h:

```
#ifndef __ConnectTree__BinaryTree__
#define __ConnectTree__BinaryTree__

#include <iostream>
class BinaryTree{

private:
    class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node * lChild;
        Node * rChild;

        Node();

        Node(int data);

    };

    Node * head;

    void addElement(int num, Node * node);

public:
    BinaryTree();

    BinaryTree(int num);

    void addElement(int num);
};
#endif /* defined(__ConnectTree__BinaryTree__) */
```

Here is my main.cpp where I create a Binary Tree object and insert objects into the tree.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BinaryTree.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    BinaryTree t;

    t.addElement(4);
    t.addElement(10);
    t.addElement(11);
    t.addElement(9);
    t.addElement(2);
    t.addElement(1);
    t.addElement(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of looking at the code for 2 hours, your time should have been spent learning how to `use the debugger` that comes with your compiler.  Within that 2 hours, you probably would have fixed your problem, and further, learn how to fix future problems with most any other program that you will write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line in BinaryTree::Node::Node(int data) implementation:

```
data = data;
```

If you still can't find, I'll edit my answer to let you know exact problem.

Comment: Derp. I forgot the `this` keyword. Should be `this -> data = data`. Thanks @NiteshChordiya